# Identify outliers of river levels that change continuously over time

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, hydrology

This is a time-dependent measure of the water level of a river measured by an instrument that measures the water level every five minutes. However, due to some interference and other factors, there are often some outliers in the water level data. Since the water level changes continuously with time, the outliers can be obviously found from the water-time scatter plot. Usually the outliers are the outliers, but sometimes the rising water can suddenly change the water level.

Since the time data is accurate to minutes, how to take minutes as the independent variable in R? How can R automatically identify and eliminate these outliers?

Some of the data and figures are shown below.

```r
df <- read.csv("high.csv")
head(df)
            time    high
1 2022-9-8 00:00 170.676
2 2022-9-8 00:05 170.668
3 2022-9-8 00:10 170.666
4 2022-9-8 00:15 170.666
5 2022-9-8 00:20 170.663
6 2022-9-8 00:25 170.657
df
              time    high
1   2022-9-8 00:00 170.676
2   2022-9-8 00:05 170.668
3   2022-9-8 00:10 170.666
4   2022-9-8 00:15 170.666
5   2022-9-8 00:20 170.663
6   2022-9-8 00:25 170.657
7   2022-9-8 00:30 170.653
8   2022-9-8 00:35 170.649
9   2022-9-8 00:40 170.646
10  2022-9-8 00:45 170.644
11  2022-9-8 00:50 170.642
12  2022-9-8 00:55 170.636
13  2022-9-8 01:00 170.634
14  2022-9-8 01:05 170.636
15  2022-9-8 01:10 170.628
16  2022-9-8 01:35 170.615
17  2022-9-8 01:40 170.615
18  2022-9-8 01:45 170.614
19  2022-9-8 01:50 170.608
20  2022-9-8 01:55 170.605
21  2022-9-8 02:00 170.603
22  2022-9-8 02:05 170.602
23  2022-9-8 02:10 170.598
24  2022-9-8 02:15 170.588
25  2022-9-8 02:20 170.593
26  2022-9-8 02:25 170.585
27  2022-9-8 02:30 170.579
28  2022-9-8 02:35 170.581
29  2022-9-8 02:40 170.579
30  2022-9-8 02:45 170.579
31  2022-9-8 02:50 170.579
32  2022-9-8 02:55 170.579
33  2022-9-8 03:00 170.573
34  2022-9-8 03:05 170.563
35  2022-9-8 03:10 170.569
36  2022-9-8 03:15 170.562
37  2022-9-8 03:20 170.559
38  2022-9-8 03:25 170.557
39  2022-9-8 03:30 170.557
40  2022-9-8 03:35 170.549
41  2022-9-8 03:40 170.549
42  2022-9-8 03:45 170.549
43  2022-9-8 03:50 170.549
44  2022-9-8 03:55 170.545
45  2022-9-8 04:00 170.542
46  2022-9-8 04:05 170.542
47  2022-9-8 04:10 170.539
48  2022-9-8 04:15 170.539
49  2022-9-8 04:20 170.539
50  2022-9-8 04:25 170.537
51  2022-9-8 04:30 170.537
52  2022-9-8 04:35 170.532
53  2022-9-8 04:40 170.528
54  2022-9-8 04:45 170.528
55  2022-9-8 04:50 170.526
56  2022-9-8 04:55 170.527
57  2022-9-8 05:00 170.523
58  2022-9-8 05:05 170.518
59  2022-9-8 05:10 170.518
60  2022-9-8 05:15 170.518
61  2022-9-8 05:20 170.517
62  2022-9-8 05:25 170.511
63  2022-9-8 05:30 170.508
64  2022-9-8 05:35 170.502
65  2022-9-8 05:40 170.502
66  2022-9-8 05:45 170.498
67  2022-9-8 05:50 170.484
68  2022-9-8 05:55 170.496
69  2022-9-8 06:00 170.498
70  2022-9-8 06:05 170.493
71  2022-9-8 06:10 170.488
72  2022-9-8 06:15 170.483
73  2022-9-8 06:20 170.483
74  2022-9-8 06:25 170.483
75  2022-9-8 06:30 170.476
76  2022-9-8 06:35 170.472
77  2022-9-8 06:40 170.472
78  2022-9-8 06:45 170.472
79  2022-9-8 06:50 170.472
80  2022-9-8 06:55 170.472
81  2022-9-8 07:00 170.462
82  2022-9-8 07:05 170.468
83  2022-9-8 07:10 170.462
84  2022-9-8 07:15 170.462
85  2022-9-8 07:20 170.462
86  2022-9-8 07:25 170.462
87  2022-9-8 07:30 170.462
88  2022-9-8 07:35 170.462
89  2022-9-8 07:40 170.462
90  2022-9-8 07:45 170.457
91  2022-9-8 07:50 170.459
92  2022-9-8 07:55 170.455
93  2022-9-8 08:00 170.455
94  2022-9-8 08:05 170.455
95  2022-9-8 08:10 170.452
96  2022-9-8 08:15 170.452
97  2022-9-8 08:20 170.452
98  2022-9-8 08:25 170.452
99  2022-9-8 08:30 170.456
100 2022-9-8 08:35 170.452
101 2022-9-8 08:40 170.452
102 2022-9-8 08:45 170.461
103 2022-9-8 08:50 170.484
104 2022-9-8 08:55 170.501
105 2022-9-8 09:00 170.518
106 2022-9-8 09:05 170.476
107 2022-9-8 09:10 170.518
108 2022-9-8 09:15 170.527
109 2022-9-8 09:20 170.498
110 2022-9-8 09:25 170.501
111 2022-9-8 09:30 170.501
112 2022-9-8 14:10 170.588
113 2022-9-8 14:15 170.573
114 2022-9-8 14:20 170.565
115 2022-9-8 14:25 170.605
116 2022-9-8 14:30 170.690
117 2022-9-8 14:35 170.805
118 2022-9-8 14:40 170.847
119 2022-9-8 14:45 170.929
120 2022-9-8 15:00 171.136
121 2022-9-8 15:05 171.140
122 2022-9-8 15:10 171.179
123 2022-9-8 15:15 171.202
124 2022-9-8 15:20 171.220
125 2022-9-8 15:25 171.228
126 2022-9-8 16:25 171.279
127 2022-9-8 16:30 171.261
128 2022-9-8 16:45 171.285
129 2022-9-8 17:10 171.326
130 2022-9-8 17:15 171.281
131 2022-9-8 17:20 171.424
132 2022-9-8 17:25 171.275
133 2022-9-8 17:30 171.279
134 2022-9-8 17:35 171.316
135 2022-9-8 17:40 171.265
136 2022-9-8 17:45 171.240
137 2022-9-8 17:50 171.227
138 2022-9-8 17:55 171.208
139 2022-9-8 18:00 171.195
140 2022-9-8 18:05 171.195
141 2022-9-8 18:10 171.195
142 2022-9-8 18:15 171.174
143 2022-9-8 18:20 171.169
144 2022-9-8 18:25 171.164
145 2022-9-8 18:30 171.154
146 2022-9-8 18:35 171.151
147 2022-9-8 18:40 171.144
148 2022-9-8 18:45 171.154
149 2022-9-8 18:50 171.154
150 2022-9-8 18:55 171.126
151 2022-9-8 19:00 171.113
152 2022-9-8 19:05 171.113
153 2022-9-8 19:10 171.106
154 2022-9-8 19:15 171.094
155 2022-9-8 19:20 171.088
156 2022-9-8 19:25 171.083
157 2022-9-8 19:30 171.288
158 2022-9-8 19:35 171.093
159 2022-9-8 19:40 171.080
160 2022-9-8 19:45 171.072
161 2022-9-8 19:50 171.071
162 2022-9-8 19:55 171.071
163 2022-9-8 20:00 171.064
164 2022-9-8 20:05 171.057
165 2022-9-8 20:10 171.054
166 2022-9-8 20:15 171.047
167 2022-9-8 20:20 171.047
168 2022-9-8 20:25 171.037
169 2022-9-8 20:30 171.042
170 2022-9-8 20:35 171.035
171 2022-9-8 20:40 171.032
172 2022-9-8 20:45 171.023
173 2022-9-8 20:50 171.014
174 2022-9-8 20:55 171.021
175 2022-9-8 21:00 171.016
176 2022-9-8 21:05 171.010
177 2022-9-8 21:10 171.000
178 2022-9-8 21:15 170.999
179 2022-9-8 21:20 170.997
180 2022-9-8 21:25 170.996
181 2022-9-8 21:30 170.993
182 2022-9-8 21:35 170.992
183 2022-9-8 21:40 170.991
184 2022-9-8 21:45 170.991
185 2022-9-8 21:50 170.989
186 2022-9-8 21:55 170.982
187 2022-9-8 22:00 170.983
188 2022-9-8 22:05 170.981
189 2022-9-8 22:10 170.981
190 2022-9-8 22:15 170.971
191 2022-9-8 22:20 170.970
192 2022-9-8 22:25 170.970
193 2022-9-8 22:30 170.966
194 2022-9-8 22:35 170.965
195 2022-9-8 22:40 170.960
196 2022-9-8 22:45 170.959
197 2022-9-8 22:50 170.950
198 2022-9-8 22:55 170.950
199 2022-9-8 23:00 170.950
200 2022-9-8 23:05 170.944
201 2022-9-8 23:10 170.940
202 2022-9-8 23:15 170.940
203 2022-9-8 23:20 170.940
204 2022-9-8 23:25 170.940
205 2022-9-8 23:30 170.940
206 2022-9-8 23:35 170.936
207 2022-9-8 23:40 170.934
208 2022-9-8 23:45 170.929
209 2022-9-8 23:50 170.929
210 2022-9-8 23:55 170.929
df <- read.csv("high.csv")
df
              time    high
1   2022-9-8 00:00 170.676
2   2022-9-8 00:05 170.668
3   2022-9-8 00:10 170.666
4   2022-9-8 00:15 170.666
5   2022-9-8 00:20 170.663
6   2022-9-8 00:25 170.657
7   2022-9-8 00:30 170.653
8   2022-9-8 00:35 170.649
9   2022-9-8 00:40 170.646
10  2022-9-8 00:45 170.644
11  2022-9-8 00:50 170.642
12  2022-9-8 00:55 170.636
13  2022-9-8 01:00 170.634
14  2022-9-8 01:05 170.636
15  2022-9-8 01:10 170.628
16  2022-9-8 01:35 170.615
17  2022-9-8 01:40 170.615
18  2022-9-8 01:45 170.614
19  2022-9-8 01:50 170.608
20  2022-9-8 01:55 170.605
21  2022-9-8 02:00 170.603
22  2022-9-8 02:05 170.602
23  2022-9-8 02:10 170.598
24  2022-9-8 02:15 170.588
25  2022-9-8 02:20 170.593
26  2022-9-8 02:25 170.585
27  2022-9-8 02:30 170.579
28  2022-9-8 02:35 170.581
29  2022-9-8 02:40 170.579
30  2022-9-8 02:45 170.579
31  2022-9-8 02:50 170.579
32  2022-9-8 02:55 170.579
33  2022-9-8 03:00 170.573
34  2022-9-8 03:05 170.563
35  2022-9-8 03:10 170.569
36  2022-9-8 03:15 170.562
37  2022-9-8 03:20 170.559
38  2022-9-8 03:25 170.557
39  2022-9-8 03:30 170.557
40  2022-9-8 03:35 170.549
41  2022-9-8 03:40 170.549
42  2022-9-8 03:45 170.549
43  2022-9-8 03:50 170.549
44  2022-9-8 03:55 170.545
45  2022-9-8 04:00 170.542
46  2022-9-8 04:05 170.542
47  2022-9-8 04:10 170.539
48  2022-9-8 04:15 170.539
49  2022-9-8 04:20 170.539
50  2022-9-8 04:25 170.537
51  2022-9-8 04:30 170.537
52  2022-9-8 04:35 170.532
53  2022-9-8 04:40 170.528
54  2022-9-8 04:45 170.528
55  2022-9-8 04:50 170.526
56  2022-9-8 04:55 170.527
57  2022-9-8 05:00 170.523
58  2022-9-8 05:05 170.518
59  2022-9-8 05:10 170.518
60  2022-9-8 05:15 170.518
61  2022-9-8 05:20 170.517
62  2022-9-8 05:25 170.511
63  2022-9-8 05:30 170.508
64  2022-9-8 05:35 170.502
65  2022-9-8 05:40 170.502
66  2022-9-8 05:45 170.498
67  2022-9-8 05:50 170.484
68  2022-9-8 05:55 170.496
69  2022-9-8 06:00 170.498
70  2022-9-8 06:05 170.493
71  2022-9-8 06:10 170.488
72  2022-9-8 06:15 170.483
73  2022-9-8 06:20 170.483
74  2022-9-8 06:25 170.483
75  2022-9-8 06:30 170.476
76  2022-9-8 06:35 170.472
77  2022-9-8 06:40 170.472
78  2022-9-8 06:45 170.472
79  2022-9-8 06:50 170.472
80  2022-9-8 06:55 170.472
81  2022-9-8 07:00 170.462
82  2022-9-8 07:05 170.468
83  2022-9-8 07:10 170.462
84  2022-9-8 07:15 170.462
85  2022-9-8 07:20 170.462
86  2022-9-8 07:25 170.462
87  2022-9-8 07:30 170.462
88  2022-9-8 07:35 170.462
89  2022-9-8 07:40 170.462
90  2022-9-8 07:45 170.457
91  2022-9-8 07:50 170.459
92  2022-9-8 07:55 170.455
93  2022-9-8 08:00 170.455
94  2022-9-8 08:05 170.455
95  2022-9-8 08:10 170.452
96  2022-9-8 08:15 170.452
97  2022-9-8 08:20 170.452
98  2022-9-8 08:25 170.452
99  2022-9-8 08:30 170.456
100 2022-9-8 08:35 170.452
101 2022-9-8 08:40 170.452
102 2022-9-8 08:45 170.461
103 2022-9-8 08:50 170.484
104 2022-9-8 08:55 170.501
105 2022-9-8 09:00 170.518
106 2022-9-8 09:05 170.476
107 2022-9-8 09:10 170.518
108 2022-9-8 09:15 170.527
109 2022-9-8 09:20 170.498
110 2022-9-8 09:25 170.501
111 2022-9-8 09:30 170.501
112 2022-9-8 14:10 170.588
113 2022-9-8 14:15 170.573
114 2022-9-8 14:20 170.565
115 2022-9-8 14:25 170.605
116 2022-9-8 14:30 170.690
117 2022-9-8 14:35 170.805
118 2022-9-8 14:40 170.847
119 2022-9-8 14:45 170.929
120 2022-9-8 15:00 171.136
121 2022-9-8 15:05 171.140
122 2022-9-8 15:10 171.179
123 2022-9-8 15:15 171.202
124 2022-9-8 15:20 171.220
125 2022-9-8 15:25 171.228
126 2022-9-8 16:25 171.279
127 2022-9-8 16:30 171.261
128 2022-9-8 16:45 171.285
129 2022-9-8 17:10 171.326
130 2022-9-8 17:15 171.281
131 2022-9-8 17:20 171.424
132 2022-9-8 17:25 171.275
133 2022-9-8 17:30 171.279
134 2022-9-8 17:35 171.316
135 2022-9-8 17:40 171.265
136 2022-9-8 17:45 171.240
137 2022-9-8 17:50 171.227
138 2022-9-8 17:55 171.208
139 2022-9-8 18:00 171.195
140 2022-9-8 18:05 171.195
141 2022-9-8 18:10 171.195
142 2022-9-8 18:15 171.174
143 2022-9-8 18:20 171.169
144 2022-9-8 18:25 171.164
145 2022-9-8 18:30 171.154
146 2022-9-8 18:35 171.151
147 2022-9-8 18:40 171.144
148 2022-9-8 18:45 171.154
149 2022-9-8 18:50 171.154
150 2022-9-8 18:55 171.126
151 2022-9-8 19:00 171.113
152 2022-9-8 19:05 171.113
153 2022-9-8 19:10 171.106
154 2022-9-8 19:15 171.094
155 2022-9-8 19:20 171.088
156 2022-9-8 19:25 171.083
157 2022-9-8 19:30 171.288
158 2022-9-8 19:35 171.093
159 2022-9-8 19:40 171.080
160 2022-9-8 19:45 171.072
161 2022-9-8 19:50 171.071
162 2022-9-8 19:55 171.071
163 2022-9-8 20:00 171.064
164 2022-9-8 20:05 171.057
165 2022-9-8 20:10 171.054
166 2022-9-8 20:15 171.047
167 2022-9-8 20:20 171.047
168 2022-9-8 20:25 171.037
169 2022-9-8 20:30 171.042
170 2022-9-8 20:35 171.035
171 2022-9-8 20:40 171.032
172 2022-9-8 20:45 171.023
173 2022-9-8 20:50 171.014
174 2022-9-8 20:55 171.021
175 2022-9-8 21:00 171.016
176 2022-9-8 21:05 171.010
177 2022-9-8 21:10 171.000
178 2022-9-8 21:15 170.999
179 2022-9-8 21:20 170.997
180 2022-9-8 21:25 170.996
181 2022-9-8 21:30 170.993
182 2022-9-8 21:35 170.992
183 2022-9-8 21:40 170.991
184 2022-9-8 21:45 170.991
185 2022-9-8 21:50 170.989
186 2022-9-8 21:55 170.982
187 2022-9-8 22:00 170.983
188 2022-9-8 22:05 170.981
189 2022-9-8 22:10 170.981
190 2022-9-8 22:15 170.971
191 2022-9-8 22:20 170.970
192 2022-9-8 22:25 170.970
193 2022-9-8 22:30 170.966
194 2022-9-8 22:35 170.965
195 2022-9-8 22:40 170.960
196 2022-9-8 22:45 170.959
197 2022-9-8 22:50 170.950
198 2022-9-8 22:55 170.950
199 2022-9-8 23:00 170.950
200 2022-9-8 23:05 170.944
201 2022-9-8 23:10 170.940
202 2022-9-8 23:15 170.940
203 2022-9-8 23:20 170.940
204 2022-9-8 23:25 170.940
205 2022-9-8 23:30 170.940
206 2022-9-8 23:35 170.936
207 2022-9-8 23:40 170.934
208 2022-9-8 23:45 170.929
209 2022-9-8 23:50 170.929
210 2022-9-8 23:55 170.929
```

Comment: "how to take minutes as the independent variable in R" - this is a coding question, get the answer in coding forums. I'd edit the question to focus on stats part to get high quality answers

Comment: Smooth the data over a suitably small time interval and investigate the residuals for univariate outliers.  You can downweight the residuals by a function of the smoothed slope so that periods of rapid change won't create spurious signals.  Exactly how you do this depends on your objectives.  Could you explain why you want to identify and eliminate outliers?  Elimination is drastic and automatic elimination has many pitfalls.